# Criar JLabel abaixo de imagem

Tags: java, jframe

Criei um JPanel de 672x750 e coloquei uma imagem de 672x672 dentro dele. Preciso colocar textos embaixo da imagem, no espaço que sobra.
Existe alguma maneira de criar um JLabel e posicioná-lo abaixo da imagem? Eu tentei, mas eles ocupam todo o espaço disponível

```
public class ContainerDeJanelas extends JFrame {

    JLabel infoTotal = new JLabel("Tempo total da batalha (em milissegundos): ");
    JLabel infoCasa = new JLabel("Tempo da Batalha em");
    JLabel infoDragaoBatalha = new JLabel("Dragões usados na Batalha de");

    public ContainerDeJanelas() {
        add(new MapaInterface());
        setTitle("Heurística Game of Thrones");
        //tamanho da tela
        setSize(672, 750);
        //usuario nao pode redimensionar a tela
        //setResizable(false);
        add(infoTotal);
        add(infoCasa);
        add(infoDragaoBatalha);
        //evento ao clicar em fechar
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //onde a janela vai aparecer (null = centro)
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Preciso que infoTotal fique abaixo de MapaInterface e que infoCasa fique abaixo de infoTotal. InfoDragao batalha tem que ficar no canto inferior direito. Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: Qual layout manager está usando? Adicione um [mcve] para que seja possivel reproduzir o problema.

Answer (score 0):

tem varias maneiras , se vc quiser fazer algo simples use o setLayout() se vc quser ter mais controle sobre seu layout crie JPanel e add() depois no seu frame 
aqui vc encontra a lista de layouts [java layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

```
public class ContainerDeJanelas extends JFrame {

JLabel infoTotal = new JLabel("Tempo total da batalha (em milissegundos): ");
JLabel infoCasa = new JLabel("Tempo da Batalha em");
JLabel infoDragaoBatalha = new JLabel("Dragões usados na Batalha de");

public ContainerDeJanelas() {
    add(new MapaInterface());
    setTitle("Heurística Game of Thrones");
    //tamanho da tela
    setSize(672, 750);
    //usuario nao pode redimensionar a tela
    //setResizable(false);

    setLayout(new LayoutQueVocePreferir());
    // conferir o link como nao sei como vc quer mostar os label 
    // nao tem como eu saber qual vc prefere usar

    add(infoTotal);
    add(infoCasa);
    add(infoDragaoBatalha);
    //evento ao clicar em fechar
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //onde a janela vai aparecer (null = centro)
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/73984)

Comment: a parte da resposta e so uma linha que ele tem q adicionar , essa linha foi mencionada na resposta , nao tem como eu saber qual layout manager ele tem q usar pq nao sei como ele que display os labels , entao creio que as "partes essenciais" foram mencionadas na resposta .

Comment: Pelo contexto da resposta, da sim para sugerir um layout, basta reler o texto.